# Get end of data segment in assembly in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly

I am trying to build a `malloc` function in assembly. My plan is to use the `brk` syscall, however in order to do this, I need to be able to know where the end of the current segment is. In c I could use `sbrk(0)` however this isn't available in assembly. Is there anyway to get the end of the data segment, aside from just putting a label at the bottom.

I am using Ubuntu, nasm, and ld if it helps.

I am assembling and linking with:

```
nasm -f elf64 mem.s -o mem.o
ld -m elf_x86_64 -o mem mem.o -e _start
```

**mem.asm**

```
global _start
%include "stdasm.s"
section .text
_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rbx, str
    call print
    mov rax, 0x0123456789ABCDEF
    call regPrint
    mov rax, end
    call regPrint
    mov rax, _end
    call regPrint
    call exit
section .data
str: db 'Hello, world!',0x0A,0
end:
```

**stdasm.s**

```
section .text
exit:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rbx, 0
    int 0x80
print:;rax = fd, rbx = string 
    push rdx
    push rcx
    mov rcx, rbx
    mov rbx, rax
    .loop:
    cmp byte [rcx], 0
    je .exit
    mov rdx, 1
    mov rax, 4
    int 0x80
    inc rcx
    jmp .loop
    .exit:
    pop rcx
    pop rdx
    ret
regPrint:
    push rbx
    push rcx
    push rdx    
    xor rcx, rcx
    mov rbx, regPrintBuf
    .loop:
    rol rax, 4
    mov dl, al
    and rdx, 0x0F
    add rdx, hexStr
    mov dl, byte [rdx]
    mov byte [rbx], dl
    inc rcx
    inc rbx
    cmp rcx, 16
    jl .loop
    mov rbx, regPrintBuf
    mov rax, 1
    call print
    pop rdx
    pop rcx
    pop rbx
    ret
section .data
hexStr: db '0123456789ABCDEF'
regPrintBuf: db '0000000000000000', 0x0A,0
```

Comment: I recommend you to use `mmap` to allocate memory instead.  It's much easier to use and you can release arbitrary pages instead of only being able to decrease the program break.

Comment: I am totally aware that this is completely impractical, I just am doing it for fun and to learn/

Answer (score 0):

The linker creates the symbol `_end` pointing to the end of the data segment at link time.  You can use this symbol to find the end of the data segment.

Comment: When I try to compile it nasm outputs an error `mem.s:12: error: symbol `_end' undefined`

Comment: @BElgy Please show your code and how you assemble and link it.  You need to use an actual linker for this symbol to be defined, generating a standalone binary from nasm won't cut it.

Comment: @BElgy Oh, I totally forgot about this being nasm code.  You need to put `extern _end` somewhere in your assembly file so nasm knows that the symbol `_end` is provided by another module.

Comment: Now I’m getting a linker error: `Undefined symbols for architecture i386: “_end”, referenced from: _start in mem.o ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture i386`

Comment: @BElgy I can't reproduce this, but `i386` sounds wrong.  Are you using the exact same linker invocation you use in your question?  On my Linux box, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The area allocated by `brk` is not continuous with the data segment of the executable unless address space layout randomisation is disabled.

To find the current end of this area call `brk` with an argument of 0. At program start the size is zero so the end address is the same as the start address.

Comment: Really?  This must be new.  Do you have a reference for this claim?

Comment: @fuz Run `cat /proc/self/maps`